# Configure requires a working autoconf/pkg-config

Tags: pkg-config, autoconf

I need to update [libdmtx](https://github.com/dmtx/libdmtx) and [dmtx-utils](https://github.com/dmtx/dmtx-utils) on Ubuntu 18.04. Both these packages aren't installed through `apt`.

I compiled and installed libdmtx with prefix `/usr/local/stow/libdmtx-0.7.7` and created all the required symlinks inside `/usr/local` using `stow` . So far no problems.

Now I'm trying to compile dmtx-utils but `configure` stops with this error:

```
configure: error: Building dmtxread/dmtxwrite requires a working autoconf/pkg-config
```

this is the search path of pkg-config (if I'm using this command properly):

```
$ pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config 
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

inside `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` there's a symlink `libdmtx.pc` pointing to the correct file to the libdmtx's installation path. But I'm not entirely sure this is important.

What causes this error? What can I do?

Comment: What about `autoconf` though? what does `autoconf --version` say?

Comment: `autoconf --version` says version 2.69

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to get build-dependencies first and then compile new version.

Use

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libdmtx-dev
```

and then compile newer version. Installation with [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) is also recommended.